# jQuery : pause slideshow on hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

So i have this code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
     setInterval(function() {
     $("#slideshow > div:first")
          .fadeOut(1000)
          .next()
          .fadeIn(1000)
          .end()
          .appendTo("#slideshow");
},  3000);
});
```

that works 100% fine..
where do i add the `.hover()` function for the slideshow to pause on hover??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Methods [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) returns a intervalID that you can use to clear the current interval/timeout using [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval).

You can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var timer;

    $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

    $("#slideshow")
        // when mouse enters, clear the timer if it has been set
        .mouseenter(function() {
            if (timer) { clearInterval(timer) }
        })
        // when mouse goes out, start the slideshow
        .mouseleave(function() {
            timer = setInterval(function() {
                $("#slideshow > div:first")
                    .fadeOut(1000)
                    .next()
                    .fadeIn(1000)
                    .end()
                    .appendTo("#slideshow");
            }, 3000);
        })
        // trigger mouseleave for initial slideshow starting
        .mouseleave();

});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/Cvxe2/)

Comment: Hi! How do I use this if I only want to pause the interval? Not clear it and reset.

Comment: You could use a boolean you set to `False` in `mouseenter`. In `mouseleave` you can set it back to `True`, and in the `setInterval`, return directly if the boolean is `False`.